# Magic method __call is not called when using a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have implemented translation following the example [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable).

In my entity, I am supposed to add the magic method `__call`:

```
class Occupation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /* ... attributes ... */

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }
}
```

However this method is not called when getting data in the following form:

```
class PostJobStep1Type extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {            
        $builder->add('occupation', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'form.occupation',
            'class' => Occupation::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ]);
    }
}
```

So I get an error:

> Neither the property `name` nor one of the methods `getName()`, `name()`, `isName()`, `hasName()`, `__get()` exist and have public
>   access in class `AppBundle\Entity\Occupation`.

Is there any way to force `Symfony` to check for the magic method `__call` too?

Many thanks

Comment: When do you get this error? When loading the entity from your database? When validating a form?

Comment: @AlanT. when loading a form. The quick fix would be to use **__get** method
`public function __get($name)
    {
        $methodName = "get" . ucfirst($name);
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($methodName, []);
    }`
But wondered If I can use **__call** instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your issue is related to the default configuration of the PropertyAccessor component. As stated [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#magic-call-method), the feature allowing the use of `__call` is disabled by default:

> The __call() feature is disabled by default, you can enable it by calling [`PropertyAccessorBuilder::enableMagicCall`](http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessorBuilder.html#method_enableMagicCall) [see Enable other Features](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#enable-other-features).

Since, the property accessor in question is likely to be constructed automatically by your form, you can't actually call `enableMagicCall` and as far as I know, there is no way to change this setting for just one form type.

That being said, you can enable this feature globally by adding the following entry to your `services.yml` (taken from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/YgH5oUMsuYk)) so that the [`magicCall` argument of the constructor](http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.html#method___construct) can be set to true for all PropertyAccessor of your application.

```
property_accessor:
    class: Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor
    arguments: [true]
```

*Note: in SF2.8, you could replace the fully qualified classname by `%property_accessor.class%`*

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you

Comment: In new versions https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#magic-call